# No sound after installing dconf-editor

Tags: 18.04, gnome, sound

On my Ubuntu 18.04 machine running gnome-flashback was working fine before  I installed `dconf-editor` and tweaked  some layout change settings. Afterwards, I hear no sound.

```
lsmod | grep snd_hda_intel
```

Resutls in:

```
snd_hda_intel          40960  15
snd_hda_codec         126976  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_ca0132
snd_hda_core           81920  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_ca0132
snd_pcm                98304  7 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_ca0132
snd                    81920  38 snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_hda_codec_ca0132,snd_rawmidi
```

Where `snd_hda_intel` is red colored.

I have removed `dconf-editor` and rebooted but still no sound.

I have also run `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/` to reset the configs to the default but to avail

**UPDATE** More info:

```
# ps -ef | grep pulse
gdm       1580  1491  0 16:09 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no
me        2015  1740  0 16:09 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
root      6057  6046  0 16:55 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto pulse
```

And

```
# pactl list short sinks
0   alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1 module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
1   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
```

And

```
# snap list
Name                  Version                     Rev   Tracking  Publisher   Notes
chromium              75.0.3770.90                762   stable    canonical✓  -
core                  16-2.39.2                   7169  stable    canonical✓  core
core18                20190611                    1013  stable    canonical✓  base
gnome-3-26-1604       3.26.0.20190621             88    stable/…  canonical✓  -
gnome-3-28-1804       3.28.0-10-gaa70833.aa70833  59    stable    canonical✓  -
gnome-calculator      3.32.1                      406   stable/…  canonical✓  -
gnome-characters      v3.32.1+git2.3367201        288   stable/…  canonical✓  -
gnome-logs            3.32.0-4-ge8f3f37ca8        61    stable/…  canonical✓  -
gnome-system-monitor  3.32.1-2-ga7c19eaeff        91    stable/…  canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes     0.1-16-g2287c87             1198  stable/…  canonical✓  -
```

The problem exists when I switch to another user.

Any tips?

Comment: "Where snd_hda_intel is red colored." I think the colouring comes from grep and has nothing to say about the module itself.

Comment: Please edit your question and show `ps -ef | grep pulse` also `pactl list short sinks` and for I wild shot `snap list`

Comment: @user966203 please see the added info.

Comment: Can we go to chat? I need more infos.

Comment: sure. what else do you need to know?